# Where to Put Code that should run First ReactJs + Mobx State Tree

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-state-tree

I have some code that grabs the users ipAddres. I do this right now in my `componentDidMount` in my `app.js`

```
 async componentDidMount() {
    await eventTrackingStore.getIpAddress();
  }
```

So I did it in my app.js as it is my root component and I only want to set this once. This works fine if the user starts from the home page and navigates through the site.

However some pages can be loaded directly(ie you type in the url in your browser and it goes straight to that page).

Since the react lifecycle starts with most immediate component, which calls a method that expects the ipAddress code to be set but it does not get set till it hits the app.js

Now I could put the above code in each method but that gets tedious. Is there some sort of method in reactjs, or mbox or mbox state tree that would fire first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use mobx-state-tree and you have a global store, then that global store can make the API call in the `afterCreate` method

```
const AppModel = types.model({
  ips: types.array(types.string)
}).actions(self => ({
  afterCreate() {
    flow(function*() {
      const ips = yield eventTrackingStore.getIpAddress();
      self.setIps(ips)
    })()

  },
  setIps(ips: string[]) {
    self.ips = ips
  }
}))
```

OR
The same thing you can do in a wrapped react component that wrappes every page of your app.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    eventTrackingStore.getIpAddress().then(res => {
      // set the ips into a store or any logic you want in order to pass them down to children         
    })
  }

  render() {
    return this.props.children
  }
}
```

Comment: Cool, I ended up figuring out the afterCreate as well though I did not know you could do the flow inside like you did first I tried afterCreate a flow but when that did not work I make another function that was a flow and called in in afterCreate. Also like your wrapper way as well.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two solutions:
You can use [react context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

> Context provides a way to pass data through the component tree without having to pass props down manually at every level.

Use context to share the store between all components and if the data is not loaded, initialize loading right there in that nested component.

If the data is already there then just take it,
`getIpAddress` method should return a promise, so in case when data is already there it will be immediately resolved.